# Object name inside of referenced .dll changed blowing up application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I would appreciate it if someone would explain to me how .NET references work when a .dll is compiled.

I have two .dll-s, my primary application.dll references my services.dll.  The purpose of the services.dll is to provide a decoupled layer for communication with third party services so that changes to the integrations do not affect the application directly.

To achieve this decoupling I have inherited the services primary object exposing and using the new object in the main application:

```
public class CustomClient : ServiceClient_v1
{
  public CustomClient(binding, address) : base (binding, address) {}
}
```

However, I am finding that when ServiceClient_v1 gets updated to ServiceClient_v2 and I try and just update the services.dll then my application.dll blows up saying:

> Could not load type "ServiceClient_v1" from assembly services.dll

So it is still hanging onto a direct reference to that other object that I am trying to hide.  I assume this is by design and simply something to do with compilation that I do not understand.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?  And why is my method not working?

Comment: Since you inherited from the interfaces/classes of the underlying service, those interfaces/classes are also a part of the public declaration of your type, you should instead use those classes/interfaces inside your own types, instead of inheriting from them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acheive by renaming the type? Do you keep the v1 class around or delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're deriving `CustomClient` from `ServiceClient_v1` in your `application.dll`, it will only work with the older version of your `services.dll` that contains the definition of `ServiceClient_v1`. As Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen pointed out, the `ServiceClient_v1` class becomes part of the public declaration of `CustomClient`.

I believe you would benefit from applying [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in your application.

In order to achieve your goal of a truly interchangeable `services.dll` you need to refactor your architecture removing the dependency of `services.dll` from `application.dll`, it should be the other way around.

Comment: This post gave the best explanation of what the issue was, and the Dependency Injection pattern ended up being a great solution for me.  I do not understand the  "refactor your architecture" suggestion, application.dll is the one that needs to reference services.dll, do I not think it could be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Define an [**Interface**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) for your `ServiceClient` type. Both `CustomClient` and `ServiceClient_v1` must implement this interface.

When you later update the code to use `ServiceClient_v2`, it should also implement the interface, which will be *unchanged*. Now everything continues to work without needing to re-complile the `application.dll` project.

Alternatively, **don't rename the `ServiceClient` type** in services.dll when moving from v1 to v2. *This is what version control systems like git or SVN or are for.*

Comment: I am going to attempt something like this approach.  This is a third party WSDL, they are the ones who keep changing the class name when they publish new versions of the service.  I am just trying to minimize the number of things I have to change to deploy using the new version.

I really want minimal or no changes to the svcutil generated code.  But it is starting to look like I might not be able to avoid that if I really want to achieve this goal.